# How to extend a response object in GraphQL with linked contents?

Tags: graphql

I've been working with restful apis. To serve a page, I needed to make lots of calls. So I've started to search graphQL.. I've read the graphql's documentation but couldn't see what I need exactly.

**Let me try to tell what I need to do:**

I've topic and document models. We can assume I've 100 topics and 1000+ documents..
I need to list all topics with list of documents linked with each topic. We make a call to get all topics then, we make calls for each topics to get their documents..

In **GraphQL**, Is there a **smarter/better way** to do that?

```
Topic{
  name:String,
  id: ref
}
Document{
  name:String,
  topic:Ref(Topic.id)
}
```

Expected Response

```
Response:[
{
  name:"topic1",
  documents:[{name:"document1"}, {name:"document2"}]
},
{
  name:"topic2",
  documents:[{name:"documentX}, {name:"documentY.."}]
},
...
]
```

**And If I extend my needing here..:**
There might be another type which will be used by Topic.

```
Category {
  name: String,
  id: ref
}

Topic {
  ...
  category: Ref(Category.id)
}
```

So, there might be multiple topics and multiple documents.. Is there a way to get categories with linked documents for each category in a single response? :)

`Category1:[Doc1, Doc2, Doc3, Doc4, Doc5]`

```
            Category1
     Topic1             Topic2
   Doc1  Doc2.       Doc3 Doc4 Doc5
```

Comment: of course this kind of response is possible ...smarter, better ? ... it depends ... 'dataloader' .... 1000+ should be paginated

Comment: As @xadm says, I think that makes sense and with the data, you describe you might want to consider pagination and filtering.

Comment: well actually I'm mentioning something else than pagination. The aim is not loading all documents.. I need to load topics with documents which are linked with. Pagination comes later.. :)

Comment: are you expecting some advanced magic? doc name and id can be resolved at topic level ... entire doc when needed at doc resolver .. just try

Comment: you mean adding a new field into Topic type? 

Currently I've sorted out my problem with loading all documents and creating a topic-docs map.. {topic:[docs...]}  And after loading topics; I merge the response with calculated map.. But it would be still good to know If there is some magic here ..

Comment: no, in SQL context ... it depends on storage/DB/update/overal requirements